# The render function in Vue component doesn't render the content

Tags: vue.js

The code looks as following:

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <test-component-2 :ElementType = "'div,red,25,div1'">CCCC</test-component-2>
    <hr>
    <test-component-2 :ElementType = "'h3,green,25,h3tag'">DDDD</test-component-2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestComponent2 from './TestComponent2';

export default {
    components: {
        TestComponent2
    }
}
</script>
```

**TestComponent2.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        This is TestComponent2
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    render: (createElement) => {
        var a = this.ElementType.split(",");
        return createElement(a[0], {
            attrs: {
                id: a[3],
                style: "color: " + a[1] + ";font-size: " + a[2] + ";"
            }
        }, this.$slots.default)
    },
    props: {
        ElementType: {
            attributes: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I run the application, "This is TestComponent2" is displayed only without "CCCC" and "DDDD".

I know I can add "slot" tag in the template, but how to do it by using render function?

Comment: Is there any console error?

Comment: There is no any console error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use arrow function syntax for your `render` function. The console says `this` is undefined if you do.

```
  render: function(createElement) {
    var a = this.ElementType.split(",");
    return createElement(
      a[0],
      {
        attrs: {
          id: a[3],
          style: "color: " + a[1] + ";font-size: " + a[2] + ";"
        }
      },
      this.$slots.default
    );
  },
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/lxl9yok3r7

Comment: It's ok. And the additional thing I had to do to make it work was to remove "template" section in Single File Component. In that case I'm able to see "CCCC" and "DDDD", but how can I use some template in such component? I've tried to add "template" in "script" section, but it doesn't work. That is I'd like to dynamically insert "CCCC" and "DDDD" as slot in already existing HTML.